# How do I configure a React router to load two components on top of each other (Overlay)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am trying to figure out how to configure my React router to load two overlaying components. I have a route `/user/testUser/item/1`. If `item:id` is in the url, an overlay component opens. However, I want the underlying component `/user/testUser/` to load as well. When I close my overlay, that is, when I switch from `/user/testUser/item/1` to `/user/testUser/`, the underlying user component is loaded initially. If the `/user/testUser/item/1` overlay is open, the underlying user component is not loaded.

```
<Switch>
                  <PrivateRoute
                    exact
                    path="/user/:id*"
                    component={ProfileView}
                  />

                  <PrivateRoute
                    exact
                    path="*/item/:id"
                    component={ShowItem}
                  />
</Switch>
```

Comment: It is easier to manage it in the component, I don't think you can do it with the routing. In the component you can get the URL and then show/overlay/close whatever you want based on the path you find.

Answer (score 1):

You can not render two routes at a time. You can manage it via optional params and render that component on a particular route.

Example :

```
<Switch>
  <PrivateRoute
    exact
    path="/user/testUser/item/:id?"
    component={ProfileView}
  />
</Switch>

const ProfileView = () => {
 const { id } = useParams();

 return (
  <>
     {id && <ShowItem />}
     ...
     ...
     <OtherComponent />
  </>

 )
};
```

You can check conditionally `id` and based on that render the other components you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really do it using routes, Switch selects only one Route's component to be rendered. You could probably experiment with having two Switch'es in parallel, but it sounds like the easiest way would be to handle displaying the overlay in the underlaying component.